# How do I view the linting errors?

Tags: plugin-coc

When editing a python file I get an error indicator (`>>`) at line 118 :

[image: vim error]

This happened after I installed the `coc-python` plugin. I understand that this line fails some kind of linting setting somewhere, but I do not know how to view the linting error. The same goes for different programming languages, for that matter ... If only I could hover with my mouse :p

Any clues?

Here are [all my vim settings](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/tree/master/common-setup/vim) and this is [my small coc config](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/common-setup/vim/dotvim/coc-config).

Comment: Depends on the plugin. They may fill the quickfix or locaton lists (:copen and :lopen for a quick look), or they may have a “hover” command you can use for more info.

Answer (score 1):

to move between errors, use

```
nmap <silent> [e <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> ]e <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)
```

You need to be at the exact cursor position for the error to be displayed in hover. So just press it in the current line.

This I haven't tried:

```
<Plug>(coc-diagnostic-info)         *n_coc-diagnostic-info*

            Show diagnostic message of current position, no
            truncate.
```

should work too.